# Justify columns in xltabular with Arial font and ragged2 package

Tags: tables, overleaf, justification, xltabular, ragged2e

I am using Arial font and the ragged2e package. Although the text of the paragraphs is justified, the text inside the tables is not. I tried to remove the ragged2e, but the I obtained several warnings. As I am using Arial font, I compile with XeLaTex in overleaf. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % Con este paquete se establece el idioma español
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Proporciona flexibilidad en cuento al uso de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % Modifica el grado de indenttación

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=CCE\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}
               
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}              
\usepackage{fontspec}





\setmainfont{Arial}


\linespread{1}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\justifying 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at ex fermentum, sollicitudin ligula dictum, mattis nibh. Cras suscipit volutpat neque eu laoreet. Fusce turpis erat, consectetur accumsan orci a, volutpat vulputate sapien. Donec feugiat ac tellus ac finibus. Sed et ultricies quam. Duis quis nulla dui. Suspendisse accumsan tellus eu quam eleifend varius. Praesent sed pharetra massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at ex fermentum, sollicitudin ligula dictum, mattis nibh. Cras suscipit volutpat neque eu laoreet. Fusce turpis erat, consectetur accumsan orci a, volutpat vulputate sapien. Donec feugiat ac tellus ac finibus. Sed et ultricies quam. Duis quis nulla dui. Suspendisse accumsan tellus eu quam eleifend varius. Praesent sed pharetra massa.






\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X 
       >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  
       c@{}}
       
\caption{Resumen de las competencias específicas trabajadas en esta UD y sus criterios de evaluación asociados (los DO se indican entre paréntesis).}
\label{tab:CompetenciascriteriosDO}\\
\toprule
\thead{Competencias específicas} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación}  \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\thead{Competencias específicas} & \thead{Criterios de Evaluación} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endhead

\begin{mycontenidos}[series] % use the optional argument "series"  for the first mycontenidos environment in the table only.
\item \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Aplicar las leyes y teorías científicas en el análisis de fenómenos fisicoquímicos cotidianos, comprendiendo las causas y explicándolas utilizando diversidad de medios. (STEM2)
\item Resolver problemas físicoquímicos planteados a partir de situaciones cotidianas, aplicando las leyes y teorías científicas para encontrar y argumentar las soluciones, expresando adecuadamente los resultados. (STEM1, STEM2)
\item Identificar situaciones problemáticas en el entorno cotidiano, emprender iniciativas y buscar soluciones sostenibles desde la física y la química, analizando críticamente el impacto producido en la sociedad y el medioambiente.(STEM5, CPSAA1.2, CE1)
\end{mytabenum} 
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Formular y verificar hipótesis sobre problemas y observaciones de los movimientos, encontrando soluciones e integrando las leyes y teorías científicas para validar hipótesis. (STEM1, STEM2, CE1)
\item Utilizar métodos para encontrar la respuesta a un problema, asegurándose de la coherencia de los resultados. (STEM2, CPSAA4)
\item Integrar las leyes y teorías científicas conocidas en el proceso de validación de hipótesis, aplicando relaciones cuali y cuantitativas entre variables. (STEM1, STEM2)
\end{mytabenum} 
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item  \textcolor{white}{aaaa}
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Utilizar y relacionar diferentes sistemas de unidades, empleado correctamente su notación y equivalencias, prestando especial atención a las diferentes unidades de velocidad y tiempo (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Nombrar y formular correctamente sustancias simples, iones y compuestos químicos inorgánicos y orgánicos utilizando las normas de la IUPAC. (CCL1, STEM4)
\item Emplear diferentes formatos para interpretar y expresar la información relativa a un proceso fisicoquímico, relacionando entre sí la información que contienen y extrayendo de él lo más relevante durante la resolución de un problema. (STEM4, CD2, CPSAA4)
\item Poner en práctica los conocimientos adquiridos mediante experimentación, comprendiendo la importancia en el progreso científico (CCL5, STEM4)
\item 
\end{mytabenum}
\\
\bottomrule

\end{xltabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you never need `\justifying`, X columns are justified by default, as are all tex paragraphs. `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` is making the default document alignment ragged, do you really want that? what is the intention of `[document]` here?

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I don´t know why I put ```[document]``` in the first place.

Comment: you shouldn't use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with an unicode engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` is making the default document alignment ragged, simply remove the `[document]` option.

You should never need `\justifying` as justification is the default, so if it has an effect it is almost always better to remove the command that is stopping justification rather than trying to repair things by resetting justification settings.

Unrelatated but never use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

with xelatex.

The first does nothing other than produce a message in the log file saying it should not be used.

The second breaks the Unicode setup reverting to legacy 8bit TeX fonts, and breaks all hyphenation as xelatex only has hyphenation patterns for Unicode (`TU`) encoding loaded.